# Где сохранять модели нейронных сетей

Tags: github, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

Часто свои наработки мы выкладываем на github, недавно я экспериментировал с нейронными сетями и хотел залить в github демонстрационный проект, хотелось, чтобы его можно было оттуда взять и запустить, посмотрев на результаты.

Компиляция проекта не очень простая (там зависимости замучаешься устанавливать), поэтому я залил туда бинарь, он небольшой, поэтому это не так страшно. Но при запуске загружается нейронная сеть, файл с её весами занимает 130 мегабайт, а гитхаб не позволяет загружать файлы больше 100 мегабайт.

Есть ли какие-то аналогичные гитхабу хранилки, где можно было бы хранить модели? Как вообще этот вопрос решают люди, регулярно работающие с ML, по идее у них подобные проблемы должны возникать регулярно, так как модели обычно довольно объёмные.